# Draw and Erase on ImageView using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, calayer, uibezierpath

I write this link's answer code to create ImageViewLayer and Imageview.
[StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997525/how-to-draw-calayer-with-line-path-like-simulate-eraser-effect)

This link gives me the below result.

[image] [image]

It's work fine .But I want ,when user press the **original** button... and then touches with finger it remove the clear area ang fill with the previous one.

And how to create Undo Functionality for this..If any question regarding this please add your comment..Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

[how to draw CALayer with line path like simulate eraser effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997525/how-to-draw-calayer-with-line-path-like-simulate-eraser-effect/23999981?noredirect=1#comment43316588_23999981)

this is the post i get the answer. there is a sample code about the effect. 
what you are different is change the gray color layer to be the "paper imager"

hope it help you

Comment: When user pressed original (in the Above Image described) button and then touch in screen, At that time the Clear mode fill with the previous one..